# How to combine results from one column and then split into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, divide

I've encountered some difficulty about combining and then splitting a column

Table: `persona`

```
Name                    date        time                InOut
--------------------------------------------------------------
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
```

Based on that table I would like output like below

```
Name                    date        InTime              OutTime
--------------------------------------------------------------
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
```

This is the code I tried

```
SELECT Name, date, time as InTime, time as OutTime
FROM persona 
WHERE InOut = 'I' and InOut = 'O'
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the expected result if MANCA GIOVANNI logs in one more time 2019-12-06?

Comment: really nice question @jarlh..... didn't thought about it, with your experience how should I handle this?

Comment: Maybe that should never happen? (Then you need do prevent it using constraints.)

Comment: Yes I understood @jarth, nice suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to separate In from Out.

```
SELECT Name, date,
       max(case when InOut = 'I' then time end) as Intime,
       max(case when InOut = 'O' then time end) as Outime
FROM persona 
group by Name, date
```

(Will perhaps need some tweaking if a person has several in's or out's the same date.)

Comment: Can I ask you what is the meaning of "tweaking if a person has several in's or out's the same date."

Comment: For each date, this query will return 1 in Intime and 1 outtime for person. If you instead need 3 different times (or more), the query will need some adjustments.

Comment: Ah yes that's true! I tried it and the query returns 1 InTime and 1 OutTime. It would be possibile to append the result? Like if the person has 2 times In and maybe only 1 time out, would be possible to repeat the person 2 times?

Comment: And if the same persons runs in and out 25 times during a day? This answer solves the question as it is given. If you think the problem is much more complex, you should consider asking a new question - with sample data and expected result that reflects the complexity.

Comment: Its ok @jarlh so you suggest to make another question with different results?

Comment: Yes, if you think it should be possible for a person to come and go many times during a day. Don't forget to have sample data with different number or In's and Out's.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have multiple Intime and Outtime for same person on same day, you can track first Intime and last Outtime by modifying query provided by 'jarlh'

```
SELECT Name, date,
       min(case when InOut = 'I' then time end) as Intime,
       max(case when InOut = 'O' then time end) as Outime
FROM persona 
group by Name, date
```

Comment: Not bad at all.

Comment: That would be one way to solve the problem! But its possible to show the person 2 times for the 2 InTime?

Comment: Can you please give sample output to make us understand clearly.

Comment: I will make another question, so users in this community won't get angry! stay tuned!