# SQL Server : combine results from one column and then split into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since some users of this community already answered at my question, I would like to ask another one with different criteria. This is the last question I asked [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213797/how-to-combine-results-from-one-column-and-then-split-into-2-columns) and I would like to improve it.

Table: `persona`

```
Name                    date        time                InOut
--------------------------------------------------------------
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:52:00.0000000    I
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:55:00.0000000    I
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  12:57:00.0000000    O
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    I
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  12:55:00.0000000    O
```

Based on that table I would like output like below

```
Name                    date        InTime              OutTime
--------------------------------------------------------------
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:52:00.0000000    12:57:00.0000000
MANCA GIOVANNI          2019-12-06  10:55:00.0000000    ? (I don't know how to handle it, maybe someone can help me think it out)
HAMPIT RICKY            2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
RODRIGUEZ CARLOS DANIEL 2019-12-06  10:50:00.0000000    12:55:00.0000000
```

This is the best answer I used to make it work, but It's limited because it shows only one person at time

```
SELECT 
    Name, date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InOut = 'I' THEN time END) AS Intime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InOut = 'O' THEN time END) AS Outime
FROM 
    persona 
GROUP BY
    Name, date
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want for the missing data? Do you want to use some other value? But your current solution is going to return a single row per person which I don't think is what you are after.

Comment: @SeanLange What do you think is the bast way to handle the missing data? Should I repeat the last Out?

Comment: I can't possibly tell you that. Personally I would leave it as NULL because there is no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select Name, date,
       max(CASE WHEN InOut = 'I' THEN time END) AS Intime,
       max(CASE WHEN InOut = 'O' THEN time END) AS Outime
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, date, inout order by time) as seqnum
      from persona p
     ) p
group by name, date, seqnum
```

Comment: that worked for me! I answerd you late because I couldn't understand what was `p.*`, `row_number()`, `over`, `partition`. That was way too many complicated query for me. I think Im going to buy your book! :)